# Add only Vuetify data table component to existing Vuejs Project

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to add Vuetify [Data Table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) to my existing Vuejs project. So when we add `vue add vuetify` its installed globally. Please help me for that how doing it

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can import the `dataTable` component alone.
You can do this in a `vuetify.js` file:

```js
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify, {
  VDataTable,
} from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  components: {
    VDataTable,
  },
})

const opts = {}

export default new Vuetify(opts)
```

and in your `main.js` import this file: `import vuetify from @/src/plugins/vuetify.js`

or you can import it in the component you need it:

```js
<!-- Vue Component -->

<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>...</v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>...</v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
  import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/lib'

  export default {
    components: {
      VDataTable,
    }
  }
</script>
```

you can read more about this in [vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#manually-importing)

Comment: I need to  do "npm install vuetify" first right?

Comment: Yes you have to install it

Comment: Hi, its given me sass-loader issue, if you are experience like that?

Comment: What exactly is the issue?